# How to set the System properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is equivalent to the below Java code in JavaScript.

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "zscaler.abc.com");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8076");
```

Comment: In NodeJS, you could use `process.env`.